# Is there an equivalent of Berkshelf, but for Puppet modules?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet, vagrant, berkshelf

Currently it seems that Berkshelf is limited to only managing Chef Recipes.

Just wondering if there is anything equivalent to Berkshelf, but for Puppet Modules ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool called [librarian](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian) which is "A Framework for Bundlers." The original use case was to download and manage cookbooks (with [librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef)). However, given its modularity it's rather easy to adapt it for other package managers, e.g puppets.

In conclusion: have a look at [librarian-puppet](http://librarian-puppet.com/).